# Conflict between luatex-ja and fontspec

Tags: luatex, incompatibility, cjk

I am using LuaLaTeX to write my thesis, because LuaLaTeX has better compatibility. However, now I found that there seems to be conflict between the package `luatex-ja` (which provides neccessary CJK support) and the package `fontspec`. I think maybe it could be worked around, but I don't know how. Here is a mini example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\setmainjfont{HanaMinA}
\newfontfamily\diacritics{FreeIdgSerif}
\newcommand\dc[1]{{\diacritics #1}}
\begin{document}
The diacritic symbol \dc{ḱe^^^^e548^^^^e535}  included in FreeIdgSerif has not been printed.
\end{document}
```

Compiling it, the following result will be printed out:[image: two symbols are not printed out]

However, if I change to xelatex and use the package `xeCJK`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
%\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
%\setmainjfont{HanaMinA}
\newfontfamily\diacritics{FreeIdgSerif}
\newcommand\dc[1]{{\diacritics #1}}
\begin{document}
The diacritic symbol \dc{ḱe^^^^e548^^^^e535}  included in FreeIdgSerif has not been printed.
\end{document}
```

The correct result will be printed out like this:[image: The desired result]

So, there seems to be conflict between `luatex-ja` and `fontspec`. My question: how can I get the same result like with XeLaTeX? Any idea?

Comment: Actually, the [][] have been inputted correctly. If I change them, I'm afraid that the source code would be not correct then. They are not shown on the website due to lack of the diacritic symbols in the browser, I think ...

Comment: They are U+1E31 U+0065 U+E548 U+E535, so a valid input would be `ḱe^^^^e548^^^^e535`. Where is it possible to see that font?

Comment: Ok, I corrected the input. Thanks! These symbols are not available in usual fonts like _times new roman_. In **FreeIdgSerif** (a linguistic font) provided [here](http://flaez.ch/freeidg.html), for example, the symbols are available. It is possible to see them, for example, in normal office programms, like libreoffice. The problem is that `\newfontfamily` of `fontspec` does not work with `luatexj`, seemingly because that it was somewhat redefined in `luatexj`.

Comment: `luatexja` has been updated in the meantime; does the new version work?

Comment: Thank you egreg! I have tested it again. But it seems that I have got a bigger problem now. My document can not be compiled at all because "luatex-ja.sty was not found". So, I have come back to xelatex. It is a pity.

Comment: I guess it has been renamed into `luatexja`

Comment: Sorry, the output is "File 'luatexja-fontspec.sty' not found" indeed.

Comment: On my TeX Live I have it: `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/addons/luatexja-fontspec.sty` Try reinstalling `luatexja`

Comment: It works! Latexja had been deleted from my texlive. I don't know why. I have reinstalled it. I have tested it with tikzposter class.  The diacritic symbols were compiled correctly. So, I think that this issue can be regarded as resolved. Thank you very much!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem solved with a software update

Comment: I voted for closing; sometimes a TeX Live package can appear as "forcibly removed" (usually, download problems). There is a `tlmgr` option for reinstalling those that suffer from this problem.